# multiple groups-boxplot-R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a CSV file with 3 levels of the parameter(C, C+Fe, Fe). Now I want to group the boxplot based on parameters by using `geom-boxplot(fill=parameter)` but only for two levels of them, not all 3.

The current code is: `geom_boxplot(aes(x = gene, y=RA, fill = parameter)` which yealds to:
[image]

However, I want to eliminate the blue box plot which is one of the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just filter the observation before plotting. Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
df2 <- subset(df, parameter != "Fe")
ggplot(df2, aes(x = gene, y=RA, fill=parameter)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```